# Ordenar una consulta por una segunda relación en laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relaciones

Tengo esta consulta:

```
$sql = Vehiculo::with(['delegacion', 'estadoVehiculo', 'franquiciaContrato', 'version.modelo.marca', 'version.grupo']);
if ($ordenarPor == 'delegacion') {
                $sql->orderBy(Delegacion::select('nombre')->whereColumn('maestro_delegacion.id', 'flota_vehiculo.delegacion_id'), $tipoOrden);
            }
$vehiculos = $sql->skip($paginador['skip']*$paginador['take'])->take($paginador['take'])->get();
```

Y si ordeno por delegación va perfecto, pero quiero ordenar por grupo que es un segundo nivel de relación.

En modelo vehiculo tengo las siguientes relaciones

```
public function delegacion(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Delegacion::class);
    }

public function version(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Version::class);
    }
```

y en modelo version la siguiente relacion

```
public function grupo()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Tipo::class);
    }
```

¿Como puedo ordenar por grupo que es un segundo nivel de relación?
No consigo sacarlo.

Gracias.